# UIScrollView only scrolling vertically

Tags: ios7, uiscrollview, scroll, uiimageview, zooming

I am trying to implement scrolling and zooming on my UIImageView but it's only scrolling vertically.

It zooms, it scrolls vertically, everything is connected in InterfaceBuilder. No constraints in InterfaceBuilder.

Can someone help me understanding why?

Thanks,

```
//
//  O_GTab2ViewController3.m
//  Safety Moment
//
//  Created by Fabio Lanza on 3/2/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Fabio Lanza. All rights reserved.
//

#import "O_GTab2ViewController3.h"

@interface O_GTab2ViewController3 () <UIScrollViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImage *image;

@end

@implementation O_GTab2ViewController3

@synthesize imageName;



- (void)setScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.2;
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.0;

    scrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.image.size;

}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return self.imageView;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    self.imageView.image = self.image;
    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTopLeft;
    [self.imageView sizeToFit];

    self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 64, 320, 455);
    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.image.size;
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;

//    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];

    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether a scrollview will scroll depends on its contentSize and frame.That is to say, if your contentSize is bigger than frame, it will scroll.

I checked your code:

scrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.image.size;

self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 64, 320, 455);

Maybe, imageView.size.height > 455, so it'll scroll vertically.

But, imageView.size.width < 320, so it won't scull horizontally.

To scroll horizontally, you should set contentSize,width > 320.